# C struct-to-struct assignment - incorrect values in target structure

Tags: c, structure, variable-assignment

I have a c struct in header file:-

```
typedef struct sample
{
char *member1;
char **member2;
long *member3;
unsigned int member4;
} example;
```

I have declared a default typedef variable in same header file:-

```
const example defaultValue;
```

The definition of defaultValue is in c file:-

```
const example defaultValue = 
{
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
99
};
```

Now in a different c file if I do,

```
example example1 = defaultValue;
```

all members are assigned NULL as expected - but "unsigned int member4" is assigned value of 0 instead of 99. This is very strange because defaultValue.member4 is 99. Can somebody please explain this unusual behavior? Is there a better way to do a default struct initialization?

Comment: The code you've posted wouldn't even compile.  You might have missed something else then too.

Comment: Make sure the second const is getting correctly referenced in your other file.  If it isn't, you'll end up with (likely) example1 ending up being filled with zeros.

Comment: Please edit your posting to literally copy the code from your actual source files. As several people have observed, the code you posted can't possibly compile - let alone give the behavior you report. So helping you is impossible, since we would have to guess what your code might look like instead.

Comment: @martin..sorry for incorrect post - quick sample. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want your header file to declare `defaultValue` like so:

```
extern const example defaultValue;
```

so you don't run into problems with more than one definition of the object.  Without the `extern` specifier  you'll have each translation unit (that includes the header) defining an instance of `defaultValue`, which leads to undefined behavior.

You want them all referring to the one in the .c file file you describe in the question, which is what the `extern` specifier will do for you.

Comment: @Michael..thanks a lot for quick answer.Yes, I missed extern. Its working fine now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to contain several mistakes (`struct` is missing its `r`, and struct's field definition should be terminated by a semicolon, instead of a comma).

Besides, if your `defaultValue` is in another source file you should declare it as `extern` in your header.